# get data from xml content in table format in postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have this xml content:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sanjay Gandhi Nagar RHS Navi Mumbai</title>
    <model>
      <instance>
        <uploaded_form_usq3zf id="Sanjay_Gandhi_Nagar_RHS_Navi_M">
          <formhub>
            <uuid/>
          </formhub>
          <group_jg6ts57>
            <city_name>7149</city_name>
            <select_administrative_ward_nam>09</select_administrative_ward_nam>
            <select_slum>272171490901</select_slum>
            <date_of_rapid_household_survey/>
            <Name_of_surveyor_s_who_collec_001/>
            <house_number/>
          </group_jg6ts57>
          <type_of_house_occupancy/>
          <group_xb9nq26>
            <group_do8xg48>
              <what_is_the_full_name_of_the_f/>
              <mobile_number/>
              <aadhar_card_number/>
            </group_do8xg48>
            <group_io6zh11>
              <type_of_structure_of_the_house/>
              <ownership_status/>
              <no_of_family_fembers/>
              <do_you_have_girl_child_under_a/>
              <if_yes_how_many/>
              <house_area_in_sq_ft/>
              <current_place_of_defecation_t/>
              <where_the_individual_toilet_is/>
              <type_of_water_connection/>
              <facility_of_waste_collection/>
              <interested_in_individual_toile/>
              <if_yes_why/>
              <if_no_why/>
              <type_of_toilet_preference/>
              <have_you_applied_or_individual/>
              <how_many_installments_have_yo/>
            </group_io6zh11>
          </group_xb9nq26>
          <start/>
          <end/>
          <meta>
            <instanceID/>
          </meta>
        </uploaded_form_usq3zf>
      </instance>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/city_name" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/select_administrative_ward_nam" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/select_slum" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/date_of_rapid_household_survey" required="true()" type="date"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/Name_of_surveyor_s_who_collec_001" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind constraint=". &lt;= 9999" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/house_number" required="true()" type="int"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/what_is_the_full_name_of_the_f" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' or  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '03'" required="true()" type="string"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/mobile_number" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="string"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/aadhar_card_number" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="false()" type="string"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_structure_of_the_house" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/ownership_status" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/no_of_family_fembers" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="int"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/do_you_have_girl_child_under_a" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_yes_how_many" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/do_you_have_girl_child_under_a  = '01'" required="true()" type="int"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/house_area_in_sq_ft" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="int"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/current_place_of_defecation_t" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/where_the_individual_toilet_is" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and selected( /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/current_place_of_defecation_t , '01')" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_water_connection" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/facility_of_waste_collection" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and not(selected( /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/current_place_of_defecation_t , '01'))" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_yes_why" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile  = '01'" required="true()" type="select"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_no_why" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile  = '02'" required="true()" type="select"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_toilet_preference" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/have_you_applied_or_individual" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/how_many_installments_have_yo" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/have_you_applied_or_individual  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind preload="timestamp" preloadParams="start" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/start" type="dateTime"/>
      <bind preload="timestamp" preloadParams="end" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/end" type="dateTime"/>
      <bind calculate="concat('uuid:', uuid())" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/meta/instanceID" readonly="true()" type="string"/>
      <bind calculate="'1c0b0cef39054d85bdf2b17bb17e4043'" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/formhub/uuid" type="string"/>
    </model>
  </head>
  <body>
    <group appearance="field-list" ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57">
      <label>Administration Information</label>
      <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/city_name">
        <label>City Name</label>
        <item>
          <label>Navi Mumbai</label>
          <value>7149</value>
        </item>
      </select1>
      <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/select_administrative_ward_nam">
        <label>Select Administrative Ward Name</label>
        <item>
          <label>Digha</label>
          <value>09</value>
        </item>
      </select1>
      <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/select_slum">
        <label>Select Slum</label>
        <item>
          <label>Sanjay Gandhi Nagar</label>
          <value>272171490901</value>
        </item>
      </select1>
      <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/date_of_rapid_household_survey">
        <label>Date of Rapid Household Survey</label>
      </input>
      <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/Name_of_surveyor_s_who_collec_001">
        <label>Name of surveyor(s) who collected Rapid Household Survey data</label>
        <item>
          <label>Amol</label>
          <value>amol</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <label>Dhananjay</label>
          <value>dhananjay</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <label>Reshma</label>
          <value>reshma</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <label>Shankar</label>
          <value>shankar</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <label>Sheetal</label>
          <value>sheetal</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <label>Vaibhav</label>
          <value>vaibhav</value>
        </item>
      </select1>
      <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/house_number">
        <label>House Number</label>
      </input>
    </group>
    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy">
      <label>Type of Structure Occupancy</label>
      <item>
        <label>Occupied</label>
        <value>01</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>Locked house</label>
        <value>02</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>Double house</label>
        <value>03</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>Broken house</label>
        <value>04</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>House under construction</label>
        <value>05</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>Permanent locked</label>
        <value>06</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>Not giving information</label>
        <value>07</value>
      </item>
    </select1>
    <group ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26">
      <label>Household Information</label>
      <group appearance="field-list" ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48">
        <label>Personal Information</label>
        <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/what_is_the_full_name_of_the_f">
          <label>What is the full name of the family head?</label>
        </input>
        <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/mobile_number">
          <label>Mobile Number</label>
        </input>
        <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/aadhar_card_number">
          <label>Aadhar Card Number</label>
        </input>
      </group>
      <group ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11">
        <label>General Information</label>
        <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_structure_of_the_house">
          <label>Type of structure of the house</label>
          <item>
            <label>Pucca</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Semi pucca</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Kutcha</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
        </select1>
        <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/ownership_status">
          <label>Ownership status</label>
          <item>
            <label>Own house</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Tenants</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Not giving information</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
        </select1>
        <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/no_of_family_fembers">
          <label>No of Family Members</label>
        </input>
        <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/do_you_have_girl_child_under_a">
          <label>Do you have girl child under age 18 ?</label>
          <item>
            <label>Yes</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>No</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
        </select1>
        <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_yes_how_many">
          <label>If yes, how many?</label>
        </input>
        <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/house_area_in_sq_ft">
          <label>House Area in Sq. ft</label>
        </input>
        <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/current_place_of_defecation_t">
          <label>Current place of defecation (toilet)</label>
          <item>
            <label>Individual toilet</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Community toilet block (CTB)</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Shared toilet</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Open space</label>
            <value>04</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Public toilet (PTB)</label>
            <value>05</value>
          </item>
        </select>
        <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/where_the_individual_toilet_is">
          <label>Where the Individual toilet is connected to?</label>
          <item>
            <label>Direct to sewer line</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Single pit latrine</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Twin pit latrine</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Individual septic tank</label>
            <value>04</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Individual biogas</label>
            <value>05</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Biotoilet</label>
            <value>06</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Non-functional toilet</label>
            <value>07</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Don't know</label>
            <value>09</value>
          </item>
        </select1>
        <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_water_connection">
          <label>Type of water connection</label>
          <item>
            <label>Individual connection</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Shared  connection</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Water standpost</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Handpump</label>
            <value>04</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Water tanker</label>
            <value>05</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Well</label>
            <value>06</value>
          </item>
        </select>
        <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/facility_of_waste_collection">
          <label>Facility of Waste Collection</label>
          <item>
            <label>MLA sponsored tempo</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Door to door waste collection</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>ULB ghantagadi</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>ULB van</label>
            <value>04</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Garbage bin</label>
            <value>05</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Open space</label>
            <value>06</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Along/Inside canal</label>
            <value>07</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Inside gutter</label>
            <value>08</value>
          </item>
        </select>
        <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile">
          <label>Interested in Individual toilet?</label>
          <item>
            <label>Yes</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>No</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
        </select1>
        <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_yes_why">
          <label>If YES, why?</label>
          <item>
            <label>For safety of female family members</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Unsatisfied with CTB</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>For better convenience</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>For elderly</label>
            <value>04</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>For handicapped</label>
            <value>05</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>For any member suffering from illness</label>
            <value>06</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>For better health and hygiene</label>
            <value>07</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Other</label>
            <value>08</value>
          </item>
        </select>
        <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_no_why">
          <label>If NO, why?</label>
          <item>
            <label>Financial problems</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Small house</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Tenant issue</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Lack of willingness</label>
            <value>04</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Satisfied with the CTB</label>
            <value>05</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Large family size</label>
            <value>06</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Drainage related issues</label>
            <value>07</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Others</label>
            <value>08</value>
          </item>
        </select>
        <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_toilet_preference">
          <label>Type of Toilet Preference</label>
          <item>
            <label>Prefab</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Material at doorstep</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Any</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>Don't know</label>
            <value>04</value>
          </item>
        </select1>
        <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/have_you_applied_or_individual">
          <label>Have you applied or individual toilet under SBM ?</label>
          <item>
            <label>Yes</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>No</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
        </select1>
        <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/how_many_installments_have_yo">
          <label>How many instalments have you received ?</label>
          <item>
            <label>0</label>
            <value>01</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>1</label>
            <value>02</value>
          </item>
          <item>
            <label>2</label>
            <value>03</value>
          </item>
        </select1>
      </group>
    </group>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get data in form following format:

```
Questions                          Label                     Value
---------------------------------------------------------------------
select_administrative_ward_nam     Digha                      09
Name_of_surveyor_s_who_collec_001  Amol                       Amol
Name_of_surveyor_s_who_collec_001  Dhananjay                 dananjay
type_of_structure_of_the_house     Pucca                       01 
type_of_structure_of_the_house     Semi pucca                  02
```

I am trying to get the data in this format.

Basically all the questions under one column say columns name is , 'Questions' , all the labels under one column and all the values under one column say columns name is 'values'.

Is that possible to do? Any help will be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
            with table1 as (select $$<html>
              <head>
                <title>Sanjay Gandhi Nagar RHS Navi Mumbai</title>
                <model>
                  <instance>
                    <uploaded_form_usq3zf id="Sanjay_Gandhi_Nagar_RHS_Navi_M">
                      <formhub>
                        <uuid/>
                      </formhub>
                      <group_jg6ts57>
                        <city_name>7149</city_name>
                        <select_administrative_ward_nam>09</select_administrative_ward_nam>
                        <select_slum>272171490901</select_slum>
                        <date_of_rapid_household_survey/>
                        <Name_of_surveyor_s_who_collec_001/>
                        <house_number/>
                      </group_jg6ts57>
                      <type_of_house_occupancy/>
                      <group_xb9nq26>
                        <group_do8xg48>
                          <what_is_the_full_name_of_the_f/>
                          <mobile_number/>
                          <aadhar_card_number/>
                        </group_do8xg48>
                        <group_io6zh11>
                          <type_of_structure_of_the_house/>
                          <ownership_status/>
                          <no_of_family_fembers/>
                          <do_you_have_girl_child_under_a/>
                          <if_yes_how_many/>
                          <house_area_in_sq_ft/>
                          <current_place_of_defecation_t/>
                          <where_the_individual_toilet_is/>
                          <type_of_water_connection/>
                          <facility_of_waste_collection/>
                          <interested_in_individual_toile/>
                          <if_yes_why/>
                          <if_no_why/>
                          <type_of_toilet_preference/>
                          <have_you_applied_or_individual/>
                          <how_many_installments_have_yo/>
                        </group_io6zh11>
                      </group_xb9nq26>
                      <start/>
                      <end/>
                      <meta>
                        <instanceID/>
                      </meta>
                    </uploaded_form_usq3zf>
                  </instance>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/city_name" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/select_administrative_ward_nam" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/select_slum" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/date_of_rapid_household_survey" required="true()" type="date"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/Name_of_surveyor_s_who_collec_001" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind constraint=". &lt;= 9999" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/house_number" required="true()" type="int"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/what_is_the_full_name_of_the_f" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' or  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '03'" required="true()" type="string"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/mobile_number" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="string"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/aadhar_card_number" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="false()" type="string"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_structure_of_the_house" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/ownership_status" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/no_of_family_fembers" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="int"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/do_you_have_girl_child_under_a" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_yes_how_many" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/do_you_have_girl_child_under_a  = '01'" required="true()" type="int"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/house_area_in_sq_ft" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="int"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/current_place_of_defecation_t" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/where_the_individual_toilet_is" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and selected( /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/current_place_of_defecation_t , '01')" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_water_connection" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/facility_of_waste_collection" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and not(selected( /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/current_place_of_defecation_t , '01'))" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_yes_why" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile  = '01'" required="true()" type="select"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_no_why" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile  = '02'" required="true()" type="select"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_toilet_preference" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/have_you_applied_or_individual" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/how_many_installments_have_yo" relevant=" /uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy  = '01' and  /uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/have_you_applied_or_individual  = '01'" required="true()" type="select1"/>
                  <bind preload="timestamp" preloadParams="start" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/start" type="dateTime"/>
                  <bind preload="timestamp" preloadParams="end" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/end" type="dateTime"/>
                  <bind calculate="concat('uuid:', uuid())" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/meta/instanceID" readonly="true()" type="string"/>
                  <bind calculate="'1c0b0cef39054d85bdf2b17bb17e4043'" nodeset="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/formhub/uuid" type="string"/>
                </model>
              </head>
              <body>
                <group appearance="field-list" ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57">
                  <label>Administration Information</label>
                  <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/city_name">
                    <label>City Name</label>
                    <item>
                      <label>Navi Mumbai</label>
                      <value>7149</value>
                    </item>
                  </select1>
                  <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/select_administrative_ward_nam">
                    <label>Select Administrative Ward Name</label>
                    <item>
                      <label>Digha</label>
                      <value>09</value>
                    </item>
                  </select1>
                  <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/select_slum">
                    <label>Select Slum</label>
                    <item>
                      <label>Sanjay Gandhi Nagar</label>
                      <value>272171490901</value>
                    </item>
                  </select1>
                  <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/date_of_rapid_household_survey">
                    <label>Date of Rapid Household Survey</label>
                  </input>
                  <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/Name_of_surveyor_s_who_collec_001">
                    <label>Name of surveyor(s) who collected Rapid Household Survey data</label>
                    <item>
                      <label>Amol</label>
                      <value>amol</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                      <label>Dhananjay</label>
                      <value>dhananjay</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                      <label>Reshma</label>
                      <value>reshma</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                      <label>Shankar</label>
                      <value>shankar</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                      <label>Sheetal</label>
                      <value>sheetal</value>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                      <label>Vaibhav</label>
                      <value>vaibhav</value>
                    </item>
                  </select1>
                  <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_jg6ts57/house_number">
                    <label>House Number</label>
                  </input>
                </group>
                <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/type_of_house_occupancy">
                  <label>Type of Structure Occupancy</label>
                  <item>
                    <label>Occupied</label>
                    <value>01</value>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <label>Locked house</label>
                    <value>02</value>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <label>Double house</label>
                    <value>03</value>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <label>Broken house</label>
                    <value>04</value>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <label>House under construction</label>
                    <value>05</value>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <label>Permanent locked</label>
                    <value>06</value>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <label>Not giving information</label>
                    <value>07</value>
                  </item>
                </select1>
                <group ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26">
                  <label>Household Information</label>
                  <group appearance="field-list" ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48">
                    <label>Personal Information</label>
                    <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/what_is_the_full_name_of_the_f">
                      <label>What is the full name of the family head?</label>
                    </input>
                    <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/mobile_number">
                      <label>Mobile Number</label>
                    </input>
                    <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_do8xg48/aadhar_card_number">
                      <label>Aadhar Card Number</label>
                    </input>
                  </group>
                  <group ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11">
                    <label>General Information</label>
                    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_structure_of_the_house">
                      <label>Type of structure of the house</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Pucca</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Semi pucca</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Kutcha</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                    </select1>
                    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/ownership_status">
                      <label>Ownership status</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Own house</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Tenants</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Not giving information</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                    </select1>
                    <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/no_of_family_fembers">
                      <label>No of Family Members</label>
                    </input>
                    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/do_you_have_girl_child_under_a">
                      <label>Do you have girl child under age 18 ?</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Yes</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>No</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                    </select1>
                    <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_yes_how_many">
                      <label>If yes, how many?</label>
                    </input>
                    <input ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/house_area_in_sq_ft">
                      <label>House Area in Sq. ft</label>
                    </input>
                    <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/current_place_of_defecation_t">
                      <label>Current place of defecation (toilet)</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Individual toilet</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Community toilet block (CTB)</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Shared toilet</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Open space</label>
                        <value>04</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Public toilet (PTB)</label>
                        <value>05</value>
                      </item>
                    </select>
                    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/where_the_individual_toilet_is">
                      <label>Where the Individual toilet is connected to?</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Direct to sewer line</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Single pit latrine</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Twin pit latrine</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Individual septic tank</label>
                        <value>04</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Individual biogas</label>
                        <value>05</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Biotoilet</label>
                        <value>06</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Non-functional toilet</label>
                        <value>07</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Don't know</label>
                        <value>09</value>
                      </item>
                    </select1>
                    <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_water_connection">
                      <label>Type of water connection</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Individual connection</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Shared  connection</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Water standpost</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Handpump</label>
                        <value>04</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Water tanker</label>
                        <value>05</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Well</label>
                        <value>06</value>
                      </item>
                    </select>
                    <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/facility_of_waste_collection">
                      <label>Facility of Waste Collection</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>MLA sponsored tempo</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Door to door waste collection</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>ULB ghantagadi</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>ULB van</label>
                        <value>04</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Garbage bin</label>
                        <value>05</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Open space</label>
                        <value>06</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Along/Inside canal</label>
                        <value>07</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Inside gutter</label>
                        <value>08</value>
                      </item>
                    </select>
                    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/interested_in_individual_toile">
                      <label>Interested in Individual toilet?</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Yes</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>No</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                    </select1>
                    <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_yes_why">
                      <label>If YES, why?</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>For safety of female family members</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Unsatisfied with CTB</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>For better convenience</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>For elderly</label>
                        <value>04</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>For handicapped</label>
                        <value>05</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>For any member suffering from illness</label>
                        <value>06</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>For better health and hygiene</label>
                        <value>07</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Other</label>
                        <value>08</value>
                      </item>
                    </select>
                    <select ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/if_no_why">
                      <label>If NO, why?</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Financial problems</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Small house</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Tenant issue</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Lack of willingness</label>
                        <value>04</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Satisfied with the CTB</label>
                        <value>05</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Large family size</label>
                        <value>06</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Drainage related issues</label>
                        <value>07</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Others</label>
                        <value>08</value>
                      </item>
                    </select>
                    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/type_of_toilet_preference">
                      <label>Type of Toilet Preference</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Prefab</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Material at doorstep</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Any</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>Don't know</label>
                        <value>04</value>
                      </item>
                    </select1>
                    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/have_you_applied_or_individual">
                      <label>Have you applied or individual toilet under SBM ?</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>Yes</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>No</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                    </select1>
                    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_usq3zf/group_xb9nq26/group_io6zh11/how_many_installments_have_yo">
                      <label>How many instalments have you received ?</label>
                      <item>
                        <label>0</label>
                        <value>01</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>1</label>
                        <value>02</value>
                      </item>
                      <item>
                        <label>2</label>
                        <value>03</value>
                      </item>
                    </select1>
                  </group>
                </group>
              </body>
            </html>$$::xml xml_content)

            select ref_select_tab[array_length(ref_select_tab,1)] "Questions",(xpath('//label/text()',one_item))[1] as  "Label",(xpath('//value/text()',one_item))[1] as  "Value" from (
            select string_to_array((xpath('@ref',one_select))[1]::character varying,'/') ref_select_tab,unnest(xpath('//item',one_select)) one_item from (
            select unnest(xpath('//select1',xml_content)) one_select from table1
            ) a
            ) b
```

Comment: hi remy, can you help me for this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196303/select-specific-data-from-given-xml-content-using-where-clasue