# Select specific data from given XML content using WHERE clasue

Tags: xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have following XML.. and I am trying to get specific data from that XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>report</title>
    <model>
      <instance>
        <uploaded_form_dc8u7x id="reportform">
          <formhub>
            <uuid/>
          </formhub>
          <household_number/>
          <Survey_Name/>
          <photo/>
          <city/>
          <date/>
          <survey/>
          <start/>
          <end/>
          <meta>
            <instanceID/>
          </meta>
        </uploaded_form_dc8u7x>
      </instance>
      <bind constraint=" /uploaded_form_dc8u7x/household_number  &gt;= 2" nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/household_number" required="true()" type="int"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/Survey_Name" relevant=" /uploaded_form_dc8u7x/household_number  &gt; 02" required="true()" type="string"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/photo" required="true()" type="binary"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/city" required="true()" type="select"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/date" required="true()" type="dateTime"/>
      <bind nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/survey" required="true()" type="select1"/>
      <bind preload="timestamp" preloadParams="start" nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/start" type="dateTime"/>
      <bind preload="timestamp" preloadParams="end" nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/end" type="dateTime"/>
      <bind calculate="concat('uuid:', uuid())" nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/meta/instanceID" readonly="true()" type="string"/>
      <bind calculate="'05ef936fe45e41d1bc08474399d64191'" nodeset="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/formhub/uuid" type="string"/>
    </model>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input ref="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/household_number">
      <label>Household Number</label>
    </input>
    <input ref="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/Survey_Name">
      <label>Survey Name</label>
    </input>
    <upload mediatype="image/*" ref="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/photo">
      <label>photo</label>
    </upload>
    <select ref="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/city">
      <label>city</label>
      <item>
        <label>pune</label>
        <value>pune01</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>mumbai</label>
        <value>mumbai02</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>ahmednagar</label>
        <value>ahmednagar03</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>delhi</label>
        <value>delhi04</value>
      </item>
    </select>
    <input ref="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/date">
      <label>date</label>
    </input>
    <select1 ref="/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/survey">
      <label>survey</label>
      <item>
        <label>raj</label>
        <value>raj01</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <label>raju</label>
        <value>raju02</value>
      </item>
    </select1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get label 'Mumbai' using value 'mumbai02' instead of all cities. so I am expecting the output as followos:

```
value      label
-----------------
mumbai02  mumbai
```

can we get above output from XML content using WHERE clause...

can we only get label 'mumbai' using value 'mumbai02' ??

Comment: PostgreSQL supports [xpath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) with function [xpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING). For your case it can be called like `(xpath('/html/body/select/item[value=''mumbai02'']/label/text()', your_xml))[1]::text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
   with table1 as (select $$
       -- INSERT YOUR XML HERE --
   $$::xml xml_content)

    select * from (
          select (xpath('value/text()',one_item))[1]::text _value,
                 (xpath('label/text()',one_item))[1]::text _label from (
                    select unnest(xpath($$//select[@ref='/uploaded_form_dc8u7x/city']/item$$
                           ,xml_content)) one_item from table1
                 ) a 
            ) b 
    where _value= ...
```